# JPA @OneToOne relation n+1 select executed

Tags: hibernate, jpa, playframework

I looked similar questions but the answers didn't worked for me..

**Problem:** when i select multiple parent entities in a query that has join fetched to some of its `@OneToOne` child entities, query executes `select` statements for each its childs. Without `join fetch` it's executing as expected.

---

`Suser` entity has the relations;

```
@OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Cascade(value = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DELETE })
public SuserStats stats;

@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@Cascade(value = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
public Profile profile;
```

---

`SuserStats` entity relation with its owner;

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn
public Suser owner;
```

---

`Profile` entity relation with its owner;

```
@OneToOne(optional = false, mappedBy = "profile")
public Suser user;
```

---

when i executed the query;

```
select u from Suser u where u.id in 
  (select f.targetUser.id from Friendship f where f.sourceUser = ?)
```

as expected, only ids of relations being fetched in a single query. It's ok. `lazy fetch` is working..

However when i change it to; (this time i want them fetched)

```
select u from Suser u left join fetch u.stats s left join fetch u.profile where u.id in 
  (select f.targetUser.id from Friendship f where f.sourceUser = ?)
```

2n+1 query being executed.. each for profile and stats relation. I tried many ways explained here but they didn't solve my problem. I guess i'm missing something basic while defining the parent - child relations ..

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the solution;

**Note:** `CascadeType` modifications are not related with problem and solution.

**Note2:** I applied same strategy to `Profile` entity, so no need to write it again

`SuserStats` entity;

```
@MapsId
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id")
public Suser owner;
```

`Suser` entity;

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="owner",optional=false,fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=javax.persistence.CascadeType.PERSIST,javax.persistence.CascadeType.REMOVE})
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
public SuserStats stats;
```

with these changes, `Stats`'s primary column became the `id` of `Suser` (as foreign key). so 
default lazy relation and join fetch on demand is working.